# day of the year to date in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get date from day of the month in a loop.  The code works for the first few days, and from then on it is returning random dates.

Any help here?

```
var now = new Date();
var initDate = new Date(now.getYear() + 1900, 0);

for (var i = 1 ; i <366 ; i++) {
    var day = dateFromDay(i, initDate);
    document.write(" Day " + i + " : " + day);
    document.write("<br>");
}

function dateFromDay(day, initDate) {
    var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

    var cur = new Date(initDate.setDate(day));
    cur = months[cur.getMonth()] + " " + cur.getDate();
    return cur;
}
```

Output:

```
...
...
Day 29 : Jan 29
Day 30 : Jan 30
Day 31 : Jan 31
Day 32 : Feb 1
// From here the output gets messed  up
Day 33 : Mar 4
Day 34 : Apr 3
Day 35 : May 5
Day 36 : Jun 5
Day 37 : Jul 7
Day 38 : Aug 7
Day 39 : Sep 8
Day 40 : Oct 10
Day 41 : Nov 10
Day 42 : Dec 12
Day 43 : Jan 12
Day 44 : Feb 13
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setDate()` on your "initDate" variable **updates that date**.  Thus, as soon as you overflow January into February, the next call will immediately spill into the *next* month.

You don't need the "initDate" variable.  Start with a freshly-constructed date **on each call to the function** for the current year, month of January (0), and whatever day number you want. The resulting Date instance will be your date.

Thus:

```
function dayNumberToDate( dayNumber ) {
  var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear(); // no need to add 1900
  return new Date(thisYear, 0, dayNumber);
}

alert(dayNumberFromDate( 271 )); // alerts Thu Sep 27 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT) (for me)
```

Comment: @sunil_mlec and of course you could make the year a parameter instead of always using the current year.

Comment: So, can I assume that parameters in javascript are passed by reference not by value?

Comment: No, they're passed by value.  If you pass in the year it would be just a simple number. Date instances, however, are mutable objects - the various `setFoo()` methods change the values inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line:

```
var cur = new Date(initDate.setDate(day));
```

for this one:

```
var cur = new Date();
cur.setDate( initDate.getDate()+day );
```

Comment: Yes there was an error, I've just updated my answer with the correct code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code given below inside your for loop before this line `var day = dateFromDay(i, initDate);`

```
 var now = new Date();
 var initDate = new Date(now.getYear() + 1900, 0);
```